# About bucket.list() of boto module in python

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Does the method bucket.list() bring whole data of file not only file information such as file name or size?

There are three files of 1,000,000 bytes in `data/hello/`:

```
data/hello/0001.txt (1,000,000 bytes)
data/hello/0002.txt (1,000,000 bytes)
data/hello/0003.txt (1,000,000 bytes)
```

and I ran my code (below).

Result size is 3000000.

It makes me think that it brings the whole data of the files and generates more traffic. Am I right?

```
conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('my_bucket')
object_list = bucket.list(prefix='data/hello/')

data_size = 0
for object in object_list:

    for data in object:
        if type(data) is str:
            data_size += len(data)

print('size: %d'%data_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `bucket.list` does not fetch the contents of all objects. When you iterate on each of the `keys` returned by `bucket.list`, boto is making separate calls to fetch the object's contents (presumably, with a generator).

i.e. it's fetching the content on every iteration of your loop:

```
for data in object:
    # data is fetched right before here
    if type(data) is str:
```

Comment: Thank you ! One more question please ^^ I closed the connection **conn.close()** before entering iteration. I expected it can not receive whole content. because of the connection closed. but, It was able to receive even though closing connection. Isn't it related to close the connection?